# local-dir alias in configuration file

Tags: spring-integration

Where can I find the documentation which says what "file:local-dir" is an alias for in the xml configuration files ?

This notation in for example used in the int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter sample files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean this one `local-directory="file:local-dir"` from the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/SftpInboundReceiveSample-context.xml#L29.

So, `file:` prefix means a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` type, which can be resolved from the `String` `location` to the real `Resource` object during application context startup with `ResourceLoader`. Right, in our case it will be `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.setLocalDirectory(File localDirectory)`. Anyway it is a Spring `ConversionService` magic to convert `Resource` from that `location` to the `File` object.

See `org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils` for more information about supported valid resource suffixes.